# How to fetch row value as a column name In Mysql

Tags: mysql

I need help with below scenario. How can we get distinct values in rows as column Names dynamically?

I have data in below format..

```
 Sno  firstName Subject   Marks
 1     ABC         Eng      10
 2     PQR         Hindi    20
 3     LM          Telgu    20 
 4     LM          Hindi    20
 5     LM          Eng      39
```

I need output in below format.

```
Sno   FirstName    Eng    Hindi   Telgu
  1      ABC        10     Null    Null
  2     PQR        Null    20      Null
  3      LM         39     20       20
```

If one more subject is added, query should be written dynamic enough to include those values too..

How can Write Query for This?

Comment: you need to clarify your question a little more... is your question about getting the `distinct firstnames` from these tables?

Comment: Make the question clear and also please try making a table format to display a table. Unsorted table data looks very bad and unreadable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns) or [Posts containing 'mysql dynamic pivot'](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+dynamic+pivot).

Answer (score 0):

Hi there as Abecee told you in comment solution for your problem is pivoting table.

Here is query for your table

```
SELECT Sno, firstName, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN Subject = 'Eng' THEN Marks ELSE NULL END) AS Eng,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Subject = 'Hindi' THEN Marks ELSE NULL END) AS Hindy,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Subject = 'Telgu' THEN Marks ELSE NULL END) AS Telgu
FROM t1
GROUP BY firstName
ORDER BY Sno
```

And here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89774/2) to see how it's work...

GL!

**Edit:**

Ok based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns) **bluefeet** answer here is dynamics solution for your problem

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
        CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN Subject = ''',
                Subject,
               ''' THEN Marks ELSE NULL END) AS ',
               REPLACE(Subject, ' ', ''))) INTO @sql
FROM t1;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Sno, firstName, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM t1
                  GROUP BY firstName
                  ORDER BY Sno');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

First part of this

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
        CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN Subject = ''',
                Subject,
               ''' THEN Marks ELSE NULL END) AS ',
               REPLACE(Subject, ' ', ''))) INTO @sql
FROM t1;
```

is to dynamically create this part of first query I wrote

```
 SUM(CASE WHEN Subject = 'Eng' THEN Marks ELSE NULL END) AS Eng,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Subject = 'Hindi' THEN Marks ELSE NULL END) AS Hindy,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Subject = 'Telgu' THEN Marks ELSE NULL END) AS Telgu
```

the second part is to create prepared statement and to include dynamically created part into this

```
SELECT Sno, firstName, 
       -- here you add dynamically created part @sql
FROM t1
GROUP BY firstName
ORDER BY Sno
```

you do that with CONCAT in this part of code

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Sno, firstName, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM t1
                  GROUP BY firstName
                  ORDER BY Sno');
```

when you create that from that string you prepare statement and execute it

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Hope that is a little bit clear now...

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89774/5) so you can see that you can compare both query and see how it's work..

GL!

P.S. if you have any question fill free to ask in comment bellow

Comment: Thanks But i need to take row name as a column Name Dynamically....i Should Not be assigned alies Name...

Comment: @user3751091 Hi there I edit my answer and add dynamically generated query. Hope that help!